# Why do MinGW and MSYS have separate versions of gcc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gcc, mingw, msys

This is my understanding of the relationship between MinGW and MSYS.

When installing MinGW and its `gcc` toolchain, installing MSYS is optional.

With MSYS installed, you get `bash` and a few other tools that *I assume* are meant to be used with the MinGW `gcc` that you just installed. However, when you run the MSYS batch script that opens up a `bash` shell, `gcc` is not on your `PATH`. At this point you do one of two things:

- You launch the MinGW installer again, and notice that you didn't select `gcc` under the MSYS category. You think to yourself, "didn't I already install gcc?" You wait for that package to download, and drop back to MSYS's `bash` shell. You run `gcc --version` and see that it's an ancient version of `gcc` from ten years ago. You then proceed to do the thing below, if you even realize that it's an option.

OR

- You `echo $PATH`, to find that `C:\MinGW\bin` is on your path, but `C:\MinGW\bin` is not mounted. You add the proper `mount` command to your `~/.profile`, and are happy to find that the recent version of `gcc` provided by MinGW is now on your `PATH`.

Why do MinGW and MSYS have separate versions of `gcc`? Why doesn't the user have access to the recent version of `gcc` provided by MinGW immediately within MSYS? I don't use Windows very often, and I was trying to use MinGW and MSYS to teach my brother C. I didn't want to be using a version of `gcc` from ten years ago. This behavior was baffling.